# Error in formating the URL for chatGPT's API

Tags: java, gpt-3

I am trying to make a program where a user can asks GPT-3 a question through its API.

I tried to get GPT-3's assistant to design code for me, however there were some errors because it uses outdated information from 2021. Below is my modified code after going through the documentation, but I still cant get it to work, it is generating a 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' error.

I believe the problem is with the formatting of the completion section of my URL, however I am not sure. If anyone could tell me what's wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class ChatGPT{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String prompt = "What country has the most moderate weather?";
        String model = "text-curie-001";
        String apiKey = /*My API key*/;

        // Encode the prompt and construct the API request URL
        String url = String.format(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions?model=%s&prompt=%s",
            model,
            URLEncoder.encode(prompt, "UTF-8")
        );

        // Create the request
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);

        // Make the request and retrieve the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder responseBody = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseBody.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Print the response
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
}
```

I know my API key is valid because changing the url to whats shown below outputs the appropriate information:

```
String url = String.format(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/models/%s",
            model
        );
```

the format "/v1/models/text-curie-001" outputs the details for the model 'text-curie-001'

the format "/v1/completions..." outputs a response based on the given prompt.

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Please read [ask] and describe your problem _before_ showing code. As in- what is your program supposed to do? What is it actually doing right now?

Comment: Okay, why doesn't changing your URL as shown in the last panel solve your problem?  None of us have a ChatGPT key to test your code.

Comment: No, it only proves that my API key is valid. It shows details on the specific model I am using. I will update the question to explain this better

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc OP isn't even talking to ChatGPT, as ChatGPT has no public API (yet?)

Comment: @Cerbrus ChatGPT has had a public API since atleast one month before I posted this

Comment: No, it doesn't have an official API. You're talking to `text-curie-001` That's ___not___ ChatGPT.

Comment: @Cerbrus **text-curie-001** is one of the GPT3 models, you can see the list here: [https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3)

Comment: ___IT'S NOT CHATGPT___. It's a different model.

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to be using "POST" instead of "GET".

Comment: This should be a comment not post

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34013722)